# Как проще изменить несколько уникальных id?

Tags: веб-программирование, sql

В таблице есть уникальный id и value к примеру:

```
id | value
1  | qwe
2  | qwe
3  | qwe
4  | qwe
```

Если я удалю вторую строку, то мне нужно чтоб 3 id стал 2, а 4 стал 3.
Как мне проще это сделать?

Может не так выразился, не нужно удалять id, а нужно переписать параметр с 3 во второй, а с 4 в 3 и т.д.

Comment: 146% что у вас ошибочная логика

Comment: Наверное менять так смело id не есть хорошо. У Вас какая задача в итоге то? Но менять наверное только простым копированием в другую таблицу без нужной записи.

Comment: @maza51, возможно в таком случае лучше говорить не об уникальных ID, а о *порядковых номерах*?

А про изменения -- думаю @Чад прав.

Answer (score 1):

Например, так (sql server):

```
update table set id = c1
from (SELECT id c, ROW_NUMBER() Over(Order by id ) c1 
FROM table where value = 'que'
) X, table where id = c
```

Можно использовать в триггере на удаление.